# App is working fine when i run from Android studio but crashing when installed from playstore

Tags: android

I recently published an app, when I installed it from playstore, the app crashes. The log I have from Crashlytics is as follows:

```
com.phoenix.gmspunch.Login$1.onResponse (Login.java:2)
retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0 (DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:1)
retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$hVGjmafRi6VitDIrPNdoFizVAdk.run (-.java:1)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8528)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

However, when I installed the same app from android studio it is working fine, with no error. I double-checked my Services and backend, it is working as expected. Can someone please help me what am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Could be when you compile for release you obscure models and that could mess up when retrofit/gson tries to map answer to model.
look into adding something like -keep class package.to.yourmodels.** { *; } in your proguard-rules

Comment: Thanks, yea i was missing proguard rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to ProGuard rules.
As mentioned in the comments by @Per.J i didn't add Proguard rules.
Added the following rules:

```
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes AnnotationDefault
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier

-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```